# Retrieve data from database (firebase)

Tags: java, android, firebase

im having trouble locating the path of my data inside the database from firebase. What will i need to put inside `mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("flamelink");` the path of the data's that i want to retrieve is flamelink/environments/production/content/contentPlaces/en-US. Hope somebody can help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To put data inside `mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("flamelink");` you have to use `.setValue()` method you will fine more [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data).
 and to retrieve from location  `flamelink/environments/production/content/contentPlaces/en-US` Use

```
   DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(flamelink).child(environments).child(production).child(content).child(contentPlaces).child(en-US);
    databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                 // here you will get data 
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

You will find more [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data) about retrieving data from database.